# Можно ли удалить элемент страницы? Например картинку.

Tags: php

Можно ли удалить элемент страницы? Например картинку.

Answer (score 1):

<img id="pic" />

$('#pic').remove();

Answer (score 0):

Можно.

А если серьезно, и именно средствами php, то:

```
if(!isset($_GET['wanna delete'])){
  print('<img src="mypic.jpg"/>');
}
```

Он не будет рисовать, еслт есть парамерт удаления

Comment: Можите написать как.

Comment: А если без гет и пост запросов. Просто человек нажал на кнопку "Удалить картинку"

Comment: @cas-live как через firebug что ли?

Comment: Это я незнаю

Answer (score 0):

можно построить DOM дерево документа, найти в нем нужный нод, а потом его удалить. Хотя можно и просто регекспом вырезать подстроку.